# How to monitor and save every email from a POP mail account?

Tags: linux, email, pop3, ubuntu-server

There is a POP (hotmail) account that I have to watch and save every email as soon as they arrive. I could do this by checking them every 5 minutes and downloading them.

But what application can do this?
(There is a server I could use 24-7 for this purpose.)

OS: Linux - Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 i386
The server is mine, full root, etc.

Comment: What OS? Do you need the app running in the background? Save the mails where? Because e.g. under Windows you can tell an open Outlook Express to retrieve every x time...

Comment: Sorry.... fixing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `unix` You can use `fetchmail` for this purpose and set up a cron task to fetch your mail on schedule.

man fetchmail:

```
fetchmail(1)              fetchmail reference manual              fetchmail(1)

NAME
       fetchmail - fetch mail from a POP, IMAP, ETRN, or ODMR-capable server

SYNOPSIS
       fetchmail [option...] [mailserver...]
```